# How to restrict the maximum count in FilePicker for Windows in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am using the [file_picker: ^6.1.1](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) package in Flutter to allow users to pick multiple image files. However, I want to restrict the maximum count of selected files. Currently, I am using the following code:

```
    FilePickerResult? images = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      type: FileType.image,
      allowMultiple: true,
    );
```

Comment: If you meant to limit the number of file selected while on the file picker dialog, then I don't think that's possible

Comment: Thank you for your response! I appreciate your input. If it's not possible to limit the number of files selected directly within the file picker dialog, do you have any suggestions for alternative approaches or workarounds that I could consider to achieve this restriction? Alternatively, is there any additional context or documentation you can point me to regarding the limitations of the `file_picker` package in this regard? Thanks again!